Help with Implementing Basket Option Pricing Code from Borovkova, Permana, and van der Weide (2007)
I'm working on pricing basket options for my research and am referencing the paper "A Closed Form Approach to the Valuation and Hedging of Basket and Spread Options" by Svetlana Borovkova, Ferry J. Permana, and Hans van der Weide (2007).
The paper provides a detailed framework for approximating basket option prices, but I’m struggling to understand how to implement the methodology in code, particularly for the approximation of the basket's distribution and the application of the moment-matching technique.
Has anyone successfully implemented this model in Python? If so, could you share any insights or pseudocode that might clarify the computational steps involved?

Have you tried asking https://www.linkedin.com/in/svetlana-borovkova-73a12b59 who now works at Bloomberg if she could share some old code?

There is a 5 step algorithm outline in the paper itself, I suppose that is not enough to get started?
